How to make VS2022 prompt to include files from external library with quotation marks (") and not angle brackets (<>)?
I am including files from external library (my sources) with:
Project Properties->C/C++ General->Additional Include Directories = ../../common/inc
When I use some class from the sources from this library, VS2022 prompts to add include file like here:

I accustomed to use angle brackets (<>) for system files, so I'd like to include my library files with quotation marks (").
How to change the behavior of VS2022 so that it suggests quotation marks (") like it did for cpp file here?
(BTW, I have no idea why it is on the list, the src folder is not listed in include directories)

It is very common to only include files from your OWN project  with "". And to use <> for anything else (even header files from a library file you wrote yourself).

I use <> for my own libraries when they are from an independent project that is not part of the workspace.

Quote and angle bracket includes have different meanings to the preprocessor. Quoted files are sought out in the project folders and angle includes are sought in the provided library paths. Usually the preprocess searches their location first and then the other location, but sometimes they just seach their location and stop dead.

The search order for "" and <> are different too so you might actually increase compilation speed by using "" too much

@PepijnKramer, taking into account that most of system files don't have ".h" suffix, this makes sense. The only problem is sorting header files. I prefer system files to be first on the list. If you use "<>" for external library, its files will be mixed on the list with the system files and it will be hard to see them quickly if the list is long. Any workaround for this except manual sorting or extension writing?

<> refers to a header which may or may not be a file. Headers are looked up in an implementation-defined manner. ”” refers to a file. It’s looked up in a set of implementation-defined locations, and if it’s not found the search continues as if the name had been inside <>.

If external header files have been organized correctly (or at least in a useful manner), their include paths should include the name of the library.  E.g. <boost/thread/mutex>, so try to setup your include paths in such a way that an include can start with the name of the library and then you can sort your <> includes based on the library name prefix. That is at least how I organize things (if a library doesnt do this you can always make your own headers with this indirection)

@PepijnKramer, thank you, this helps. Just for the sake of example here, if I use (as mentioned the question above) folder "common" which is two levels higher than the project, would you recommend to set C/C++ General->Additional Include Directories as "../../" and use "common/inc/log.h" in source code? I am still not very happy with this "redundant" inc here, but with this approach still don't see better ways. Correct me, please, if I am wrong here.

@PeteBecker, thank you, but what's your source for this? Especially, for "may not be a file"? I am looking into the Source file inclusion and see the only difference in h-char and q-char which is no way related to "may or may not be a file", at least how I understand it. I could be wrong, since this (<> vs "" in these terms) is kind of dark waters (at least for me), so I would be thankful for any explanation of the details here.

@DamirTenishev -- look at notes 1) and 2) in your link. 1) says it looks for a "header"; 2) says it looks for a "source file". That difference is deliberate: <> does not have to refer to a "source file". Note 4) refers to "header or source file", again pointing out that they are different things. The underlying idea was that the compiler could "know" about the standard headers, and not require an actual file anywhere.

@PeteBecker, thank you, the example with "know" helped to grasp the idea. In this case with the "...It may fallback to (1) and treat q-char-sequence as a header identifier." from the same page, what have you meant with your original comment in the scope of this question? Were you answering to it or to some of later comments? I just can't see how to make use of it. By this comment and aforementioned "fallback" I still can use and of <> and "" for my library headers. So, what's your point in this case?

@PepijnKramer, on the "The search order for "" and <> are different too so you might actually increase compilation speed by using "" too much", don't get me wrong, but do you really think that searching for a file could make real impact against time of preprocessing and compilation (and processing nested files)? Do you have real experience with such impacts or this is just a speculation? I mean with famous "premature optimization is the root of all evil", is this a real underwater stone to care about or some "horror story"?

@DamirTenishev -- I was responding to compiler-specific rules like "quoted files are sought out in the project folders and angled files are sought in the provided library paths".

@DamirTenishev You are ofcourse right finding a file is a small part of the overall build time. It used to matter when I started with C++ (over 30 years ago :/ ) and seeking files on disk was really slow), I just realize I didn't update that mental picture and never measured it again :)
